# Api Post Call always inserts An empty object to mongoDb

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Im Currently working on a angular app that uses a self writeen Api to get and post Data to a MongoDb Database.

Getting data from a Get call from the angular app is no Problem. Also is Posting data through Postman to the db no Problem. The Problem ist i cant pust my Data from my angular app. iam specifying a Body which also seem correctly filled. After sending the request followin data structure is inserted in Mongo DB [Datastructure inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkyJh.png):

Here is my Cde from the Call from the angular app:

```
    WriteToDb(pName: string, pDes: string, pPrice: string) {


        const p = new product(pName, pDes, pPrice);

        console.log(p.Preis);
        console.log(p.beschreibung);
        console.log(p.name);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(p));


        this.http.post("MyUrl/api/products", JSON.stringify(p)).subscribe((res) => {

            console.log(res);
        })

    }
```

heres my Endpoint in the product.js File

```
})const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const product = require('../models/product')





router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    const ProductPost = new product({
        produktName: req.body.produktName,
        produktBeschreibung: req.body.produktBeschreibung,
        lagerbestand: req.body.lagerbestand
    })
    try {
        const newProd = await ProductPost.save()
        res.status(201).json(newProd)
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })

    }





module.exports = router
```

heres the mongoose Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

produktName: String,
produktBeschreibung: String,
lagerbestand: String

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',ProductSchema)
```

I want that the data that i am giving to the body is inserted into the MongoDb DB

Comment: have you tried executing the http.post without JSON.stringify, i.e. passing the object directly to it: `this.http.post("MyUrl/api/products", p).subscri.......`